# ubuntu 22.04 server install fails: proxmox

Tags: server, system-installation, virtualization, proxmox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 server on a Proxmox VM, but the installer always fails while processing the firmware package (see image). I already tried many settings for the VM, now I'm stuck there without any other ideas.

[image: Installation error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was just a disk space problem. I was going with 4 Gig, being the requirement 2,5 Gig and it wasn't enough.

Went with 8 and everything worked out,